# Error durin installation of a program

Tags: release-juno, software-installation

During the installation of a software (Abaqus) the following error appears:

```
An error occurred while executing the action.
Technical details:
Creating child process failed. Log ID is 0001
/home/luca/Documents/PC_Utilities/Abaqus/4/SIMULIA_fesafe/Linux64/1/inst/common/installationFiles/code/unzip -qo "/home/luca/Documents/PC_Utilities/Abaqus/4/SIMULIA_fesafe/Linux64/1/inst/common/installationFiles/code/siteIDandDslsStat.zip" -d "/tmp/DSY_20190325T225926+0100/tmp"
Stdout:
Stderr: unzip: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
Action LaunchAppAction from feature CODE\linux_a64\SMATocLicPanel failed.
Action ID: unzip_siteIDandDslsStat
```

Anyone knows what is it and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Kevin-Mattheus-Moerman/Abaqus-Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) you have a guide on how to install Abaqus on Juno.

Comment: I already asked the same question in that page. I have tfollowed that procedure

Answer (score -1):

Please try to do the following commands (in a terminal window)

```
$ LANG=en_US
$ sudo ./StartGUI.sh
```

good luck!